How to implement fault tolerant cat state construction with qiskit?
I want to build a fault-tolerant error correction gadget in qiskit. As a part of that, I want to construct cat states (for the syndrome measurements) in a fault-tolerant way.
One way to do this, is to naivly (that is: non-fault-tolerantly) construct the GHZ state and then perform the ZZ parity measurements. If any of those parity measurements signals an error, start over. If not, we trust the GHZ state.
In order to implement this in qiskit I tried to make use of classical feedforward and control flow. However, it starts getting ugly here.
What I need is a while_loop that runs as long as any of the measured parities is not 0. But while_loop does not seem to accept logical nots, ors or ands in its loop condition (even though, OpenQASM allows those concepts)
I came up with the following ugly workaround:
q_cat = QuantumRegister(3, 'cat') 
q_anc = QuantumRegister(1, 'anc') 
c_meas = ClassicalRegister(2, 'meas')

q_cat_preparation = QuantumCircuit(q_cat) 
q_cat_preparation.reset(q_cat)
q_cat_preparation.h(q_cat[0])
q_cat_preparation.cx(q_cat[0], q_cat[1])
q_cat_preparation.cx(q_cat[0], q_cat[2])

qc = QuantumCircuit(q_cat, q_anc, c_meas)

with qc.while_loop((c_meas[0], 0)):
    qc.compose(q_cat_preparation, q_cat, inplace=True)
    qc.reset(q_anc)
    qc.cx(q_cat[0], q_anc)
    qc.cx(q_cat[1], q_anc)
    qc.measure(q_anc, c_meas[0])
    qc.reset(q_anc)
    qc.cx(q_cat[1], q_anc)
    qc.cx(q_cat[2], q_anc)
    qc.measure(q_anc, c_meas[1])
    qc.reset(q_anc)
    qc.x(q_anc) 
    with qc.if_test((c_meas[0], 1)): 
        qc.reset(q_anc)
    with qc.if_test((c_meas[1], 1)): 
        qc.reset(q_anc) 
    qc.measure(q_anc, c_meas[0])

which looks like this:

Notice, that I reused the ancilla qubit to cope for the logical or that I would actually like to put into the while_loop condition.
My first issue with this is:
It is ugly and becomes even uglier for cat states involving more qubits.
My second issue (which is even worse) is that it does not seem to work with a noise model. This is my noise model:
from qiskit_aer.noise import depolarizing_error, NoiseModel

e1 = depolarizing_error(0.001, 1)
e2 = e1.tensor(e1)

nm = NoiseModel() 
nm.add_all_qubit_quantum_error(e1, ['u1', 'u2', 'u3', 'h'])
nm.add_all_qubit_quantum_error(e2, ['cx', 'cz'])

Simulating the circuit with the noise model interestingly works only sometimes:
sim = AerSimulator(noise_model = nm)
circ = transpile(qc, sim)
counts = sim.run(circ, shots = 10).result().get_counts()
counts

This code sometimes terminates. Sometimes it does not and I have to interrupt the kernel. I do not understand why. I would assume that the qubit reset at the beginning of the while_loop ensures that I start over from scratch after the cat state creation failed.
So, my main issue where I need help is this:
For my main quest of simulating fault-tolerant error correction, have I used a reasonable approach after all? Should I rather use other technologies, other simulators, other frameworks than qiskit, other fault-tolerant schemes? Or is there simply a bug in my implementation?
If I have to abandon qiskit I would prefer to still use an OpenQASM-based framework.
